# Parse an XML into a string with nested parentheses

Tags: javascript, arrays, text, string-formatting

I'm trying to cycle through an XML string with a regular expression in order to build a meaningful string from it.

The XML represents a nested boolean expression.

I have it so it will extract the values that are part of equalities, but I can't figure out how to get the AND/OR operators, nor the parenthesis that are needed in the final result.

This is what the XML looks like:

```
<applic id="TCTO_709_PRE_ALL">
<displayText><simplePara>All Aircraft without Extended Range Capability</simplePara></displayText>
<!--BEGIN OR-->
<evaluate andOr="or"> 
<!-- ( -->
  <assert applicPropertyIdent="partno" applicPropertyType="prodattr" applicPropertyValues="UHK97000-15" />
<!--BEGIN AND-->
 <evaluate andOr="and">     
  <!-- ( -->
<!--BEGIN OR-->
     <evaluate andOr="or">
     <!-- ( -->
        <assert applicPropertyIdent="partno" applicPropertyType="prodattr" applicPropertyValues="UHK97000-10" />
        <assert applicPropertyIdent="partno" applicPropertyType="prodattr" applicPropertyValues="UHK97000-12" />
     <!-- ) -->
     </evaluate>
<!--BEGIN OR-->
     <evaluate andOr="or">
      <!-- ( -->
        <assert applicPropertyIdent="TCTO_1Q-9A-709" applicPropertyType="condition" applicPropertyValues="PRE" />
        <assert applicPropertyIdent="TCTO_1Q-9A-709" applicPropertyType="condition" applicPropertyValues="NOI" />
      <!-- ) -->
     </evaluate>
     <!-- ) -->
  </evaluate>
  <!-- ) -->
 </evaluate>
</applic>
```

All the `<assert>` elements are enclosed in AND or OR `<evaluate>` elements.

This is the desired result for that XML:

```
(partno="UHK97000-15" or ((partno="UHK97000-10" or partno="UHK97000-12") and (TCTO_1Q-9A-709="PRE" or TCTO_1Q-9A-709="NOI")))
```

Here is my script I am trying with:

```
var sApplic = '<applic id="TCTO_709_PRE_ALL"><displayText><simplePara>All Aircraft without Extended Range Capability</simplePara></displayText><evaluate andOr="or"><assert applicPropertyIdent="partno" applicPropertyType="prodattr" applicPropertyValues="UHK97000-15"></assert><evaluate andOr="and"><evaluate andOr="or"><assert applicPropertyIdent="partno" applicPropertyType="prodattr" applicPropertyValues="UHK97000-10"></assert><assert applicPropertyIdent="partno" applicPropertyType="prodattr" applicPropertyValues="UHK97000-12"></assert></evaluate><evaluate andOr="or"><assert applicPropertyIdent="TCTO_1Q-9A-709" applicPropertyType="condition" applicPropertyValues="PRE"></assert><assert applicPropertyIdent="TCTO_1Q-9A-709" applicPropertyType="condition" applicPropertyValues="NOI"></assert></evaluate></evaluate></evaluate></applic>';
var sRegXEval = /<assert applicPropertyIdent="(.*?)" applicPropertyType=".*?" applicPropertyValues=(".*?")(\/>|<\/assert>)?/g;
var sMatch = sRegXEval.exec(sApplic);
while (sMatch != null) { 
        var sFirst = sMatch[1] + "=" + sMatch[2];
          document.write("<p>sMatch[" + i +"]" + sFirst);
    sMatch = sRegXEval.exec(sApplic);
    i++;
}
</script>
```

Here are the results of that script, which are still far from the desired result:

```
sMatch[0]partno="UHK97000-15"
sMatch[1]partno="UHK97000-10"
sMatch[2]partno="UHK97000-12"
sMatch[3]TCTO_1Q-9A-709="PRE"
sMatch[4]TCTO_1Q-9A-709="NOI"
```

How can I improve the code to get the desired result?

**UPDATED**
The XML string has changed to

```
var sApplic = '<datamodule><file>CClasic.sgm</file><applic><displayText><simplePara>Cooking Classics</simplePara></displayText><assert applicPropertyIdent="author" applicPropertyType="prodattr" applicPropertyValues="Crocker"/></applic></datamodule>';
```

Since I've done this the code @trincot gave me no longer works. How do I improve the script to take in this new string and allow me to also display the file name in the  element?

Comment: Please try to be clearer when asking questions here. What is formula results? What is test subject? You have not even written the desired output. I hate it when someone really wants help but fails to ask for it properly. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I deleted my answers and modified my first question to hopefully clarify things better. Thank you for the information.

Comment: The values I'm extracting are
        applicPropertyIdent="VALUE1" 
        applicPropertyValues="VALUE2"
The array pulls them in the script with the regular expression. What I'm having trouble with is getting the parenthesis added before and after the <evalu...> elements. What's particularly tricky is you have to add the <evaluate andOr="or"> (OR/AND) after the arrays found value. For example (partno="PRE" or  .That's what I can't figure out what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not try to parse XML with regular expressions: they are not well suited for such a task.

Instead use the [DOM parser that the Web API offers in all major browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), and a recursive function that will take care of inserting the boolean operators and parentheses:

```js
function parse(node) {
    return Array.from(node.children, child =>
        child.tagName === 'assert'
            ? child.getAttribute('applicPropertyIdent') 
                + '="' + child.getAttribute('applicPropertyValues') + '"'
            : child.tagName === 'evaluate'
                ? '(' + parse(child) + ')'
                : parse(child)
    ).filter(Boolean).join(' ' + node.getAttribute('andOr') + ' ');
}

const sApplic = `<datamodule>
<file>CClasic.sgm</file>
<applic id="TCTO_709_PRE_ALL"> 
    <displayText>
        <simplePara>All Aircraft without Extended Range Capability</simplePara>
    </displayText>
    <evaluate andOr="or">
        <assert applicPropertyIdent="partno" applicPropertyType="prodattr" applicPropertyValues="UHK97000-15"></assert>
        <evaluate andOr="and">
            <evaluate andOr="or">
                <assert applicPropertyIdent="partno" applicPropertyType="prodattr" applicPropertyValues="UHK97000-10"></assert>
                <assert applicPropertyIdent="partno" applicPropertyType="prodattr" applicPropertyValues="UHK97000-12"></assert>
            </evaluate>
            <evaluate andOr="or">
                <assert applicPropertyIdent="TCTO_1Q-9A-709" applicPropertyType="condition" applicPropertyValues="PRE"></assert>
                <assert applicPropertyIdent="TCTO_1Q-9A-709" applicPropertyType="condition" applicPropertyValues="NOI"></assert>
            </evaluate>
        </evaluate>
    </evaluate>
    </applic>
</datamodule>`; 

const xml = ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString(sApplic, "text/xml");
const result = parse(xml.documentElement);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is so incredible, thank you. The beg thing is I'm running this on ten thousand documents, so I need to be able to run this on such a big scale. And this is the only part of the script.  I'm used to using a text editor (UltraEditStudio) not the DOM parser. For awhile I used XSLT but that skill went away as work deadlines became persistent.

Comment: I needed to expand my XML string to include the file name and now must extract it, the applic id and simplePara values.

Comment: The string structure is <datamodule><file>filename</file><applic>....</applic>
I tried to use sApplic.getElementsByTagName("file")[0}; but this just resulted in errors. And with the new string value the script above will no longer work.

Is there a way start the parsing at the <datamodule> element then allow me to traverse and extract these extra values? @trincot